# Accessing User defined service in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, connection-pooling, cloud-foundry

I am working on spring boot application which uses REST webservices. Till now , all the database paaswords i used to store in my application.properties class and am using HICKARI CP also to manage the connection pooling.

But now , i have created the user services in Cloud foundry and have included the script of CF in my build.gradle file too.
But i do not have any idea as to how shall i access these services within my code and how can i autowire thise datasources. Please advice any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use Spring cloud service connector. This is sub project of Springs cloud.

```
http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-connectors/spring-cloud-spring-service-connector.html#_relational_database_db2_mysql_oracle_postgresql_sql_server
```

you can create a mysql service inside your cloud foundry space. And the bind the same to your app. This can be done as defining services inside your manifest.yml or using bind-service command in cf cli.

You can add spring cloud service connector dependencies in your gradle build and add datasource configuration bean.

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    return connectionFactory().dataSource("your-mysql-service-name");
}
```

This creates a datasource of the mysql service in your application, and registers as a bean in spring context. That can be autowired where ever needed.

Alternatively, cloud foundry exposes the details about every service that application is binded to, in VCAP_SERVICES env variable. Once your application is binded to service, you can find your mysql service username, password, connection url, db name etc in this variable. You can read this variable and parse the values and build a datasource of your own.

Using service connectors are preferred approach as the infrastructure code is handled by springs.

Comment: I see Spring Cloud Connectors are an *over-kill* to do any of such configurations as that needs one to package the big libraries and makes the app even bigger when deployed. **CF ENV** are the simplest, cheapest and easiest way to achieve it. Use of CF UPS is also an overkill as that does **absolutely nothing** more than exposing the values in VCAP_SERVICES, which you could anyways achieve by CF ENV. Keep it simple!

Comment: The whole idea of Springs cloud connectors is to abstract the cloud and make user code unaware of the underlying infrastructure. It may be a overhead from the point of dependencies in your application, but it really has many benefits. If you want to move to a different cloud, then there is absolutely no change required to your code.

Comment: Yes, agreed! The connectors are there to follow the 'config' factor out of 12-factors i.e. to keep configurations out of the code to keep the code cloud provider and more importantly environment agnostic. But this is not the only way to achieve it. Like Cloud Connectors, Environment (CF env, or Spring Container env or others) is one of the other (simpler and powerful) way to externalise config. CC may have some edge cases to cover (I'm still to find one though) but otherwise adds to code debt and makes it little extra effort for new-joiners to understand it. I had prefer keep it simple :-)